# changing chars encryption program

Tags: java

I'm really loosing my hair over this one. Im making a (simple) encryption program. 
Its supposed to take the char make it to an int, add 13 and convert back to a char. Then its supposed to do the same in reverse order. But my only outprint is two blank lines? I know the problem is when I convert back to letters for when I print x everything works. The part I've commented out was something I tried, and while I got an output endtwo was newer like the original text. Also I have to do this in modul 26.

```
      String str = ("helloworld");
      String end ="";
      String endtwo ="";

      for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        int x = str.charAt(i);
        x = ((char)((x+13)%26));
        char u =(char)x;
        end += u; 
        //end += ((char)(str.charAt(i)+13));
      }

      for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        int x = str.charAt(i);
        x = ((char)((x-13)%26));
        char u =(char)x;
        endtwo += u; 
       //endtwo += ((char)(str.charAt(i)-13));
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java a char is an integer. Notice that the line

```
 int x = str.charAt(i);
```

returns an integer which represents the character at the ith location in the String. So what is the value of the integer? You can look up the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the letters of the alphabet. You will see that lower case h is 104 in decimal. So you then add 13 to this value so

```
  104 + 13 = 117
```

You then proceed to mod by 26 which reduces the value to a range 0 to 25.

```
  117 % 26 = 13
```

Decimal 13 in the ASCII table represents the carriage return character.

Similarly, going the other way you are starting with the 13 and subtracting 13 giving 0 then 0 mod 26 is 0 so 0 is the null character in the ASCII table.

Therefore, rethink your strategy for the encryption algorithm. For example, to get a simple cyclic cipher you can subtract the lower case character 'a' from the character to be encoded.

```
   x = x - 'a';
   x = x + 13;
   x = x % 26;
   x = x + 'a';
```

This guarantees that you end up with a letter of the alphabet. But only lower case though. How would you modify this to cater for upper case as well?

Also think carefully about the decipher step at the end. Subtracting 13 does not necessarily give you the answer you expect. Hint: Try running the cipher text through the exact same process as the encryption and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach to implement the ROT13 encryption algorithm is to check in wich range of ASCCI codes is each character, then add 13 or sub 13 depending on the range:

```
String str = "helloworld";

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {  
    char c = str.charAt(i);

    if (c >= 'A' && c < 'N' || c >= 'a' && c < 'n') {         
        c += 13;                          
    } else if (c >= 'N' && c <= 'Z' || c >= 'n' && c <= 'z') {    
        c -= 13;                                              
    } 
}
```